# Numpy array slicing to return sliced array and corresponding array indices

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I'm trying to generate two numpy arrays from one. One which is a slice slice of an original array, and another which represents the indexes which can be used to look up the values produced. The best way I can explain this is by example:

```
import numpy as np

original = np.array([
    [5, 3, 7, 3, 2],
    [8, 4, 22, 6, 4],
])

sliced_array = original[:,::3]
indices_of_slice = None # here, what command to use?

for val, idx in zip(np.nditer(sliced_array), np.nditer(indices_of_slice)):
    # I want indices_of_slice to behave the following way:
    assert val == original[idx], "Error. This implementation is not correct. "
```

Ultimately what I'm aiming for is an array which I can iterate through with `nditer`, and a corresponding array `indices_of_slices`, which returns the original lookup indices `(i,j,...)`. Then, the value of the sliced array should be equal to value of the original array in index (i,j,...).

Main question is: Can I return both the new sliced array as well as the indices of the values when slicing a numpy array? Hopefully all is clear!

Edit: Here are the expected printouts of the two arrays:

```
# print(sliced_array)
# >>> [[5 3]
# >>>  [8 6]]

# expected result of 
# print(indices_of_slice)
# >>> [[(0 0) (0 3)]
# >>>  [(1 0) (1 3)]]
```

Comment: Expected output for the example would clarify the question more than an explanation.

Comment: @MichaelSzczesny Added now. The result I need has shape+1 of the original, since in each previous 'value' slot, you need indices (i,j,k,...).

Comment: That's what I'm thinking too. Creating an `mgrid` and then slicing the same way as the `sliced_array` makes sense, but it's very difficult to generalize to higher dimensions and then use to fetch values from the original

Comment: That's ok. I'm not sure why this is nowhere to be found though, or so difficult to create. An array of shape (n,m,...) which has values equal to their own indices

Comment: The use of `nditer` was just for the sake of the example, meant to convey how the `sliced_array` and `indices_of_slice` arrays are linked through the `assert` statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use numpy's slice [`np.s_[]`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html) with a tiny bit of gymnastics to get the indices you are looking for:

```py
slc = np.s_[:, ::3]

shape = original.shape
ix = np.unravel_index(np.arange(np.prod(shape)).reshape(shape)[slc], shape)

>>> ix
(array([[0, 0],
        [1, 1]]),
 array([[0, 3],
        [0, 3]]))

>>> original[ix]￼
array([[5, 3],
       [8, 6]])

>>> original[slc]
array([[5, 3],
       [8, 6]])
```

Note that this works with slices that have some reverse direction:

```py
slc = np.s_[:, ::-2]

# ... (as above)

>>> ix
(array([[0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 1]]),
 array([[4, 2, 0],
        [4, 2, 0]]))

>>> np.array_equal(original[ix], original[slc])
True
```

Comment: Your suggestion of `np.unravel_index(np.arange(np.prod(shape)).reshape(shape)[slc], shape)` is great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
In [22]: original = np.array([
    ...:     [5, 3, 7, 3, 2],
    ...:     [8, 4, 22, 6, 4],
    ...: ])    
In [23]: sliced_array = original[:,::3]
```

Make a boolean array with the same slicing:

```
In [24]: mask = np.zeros(original.shape, dtype=bool)    
In [25]: mask[:,::3] = True    
In [26]: mask
Out[26]: 
array([[ True, False, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False,  True, False]])
```

`mask` selects the same values - but in raveled form:

```
In [27]: sliced_array
Out[27]: 
array([[5, 3],
       [8, 6]])

In [28]: original[mask]
Out[28]: array([5, 3, 8, 6])
```

We can get indices from the mask:

```
In [30]: idx = np.argwhere(mask)

In [31]: idx
Out[31]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 3]], dtype=int64)
```

And iteratively apply them:

```
In [32]: for ij,v in zip(idx, sliced_array.ravel()):
    ...:     print(original[tuple(ij)], v)
    ...:     
5 5
3 3
8 8
6 6
```

Testing this with advanced indexing:

```
In [49]: aslc = ([[0],[1]], [0,2,4])

In [50]: sliced_array = original[aslc]; sliced_array
Out[50]: 
array([[ 5,  7,  2],
       [ 8, 22,  4]])

In [51]: mask = np.zeros(original.shape, dtype=bool); mask[aslc] = True; mask
Out[51]: 
array([[ True, False,  True, False,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, False,  True]])

In [52]: idx = np.argwhere(mask); idx
Out[52]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 2],
       [0, 4],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 2],
       [1, 4]], dtype=int64)

In [54]: original[mask]
Out[54]: array([ 5,  7,  2,  8, 22,  4])

In [55]: for ij,v in zip(idx, sliced_array.ravel()):
    ...:     print(original[tuple(ij)], v)
    ...:     
5 5
7 7
2 2
8 8
22 22
4 4
```

This doesn't work with all variations of advanced indexing; for example, indices the reverse the order or duplicate rows won't match.

```
In [66]: aslc = (slice(None,None,-1),slice(3,None,-3))

In [67]: sliced_array = original[aslc]; sliced_array
Out[67]: 
array([[6, 8],
       [3, 5]])

In [68]: mask = np.zeros(original.shape, dtype=bool); mask[aslc] = True; mask
Out[68]: 
array([[ True, False, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False,  True, False]])

In [69]: original[mask]
Out[69]: array([5, 3, 8, 6])
```

`mask` selects the same values, but in a different order.

The `slice` is a `view` of `original`.  That is it uses the same `data`.  But it starts at a different point, and uses different strides.

```
In [70]: original.__array_interface__
Out[70]: 
{'data': (2697031319568, False),
 'strides': None,
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'shape': (2, 5),
 'version': 3}

In [71]: sliced_array.__array_interface__
Out[71]: 
{'data': (2697031319600, False),
 'strides': (-20, -12),
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'shape': (2, 2),
 'version': 3}
```

In general, `numpy` indexing is a one-way street.  It creates a new array, whether view or copy, that has the desired values, but it does not create, or return, a mapping, or a reverse mapping.  Except for some special cases, we can't identify where in `original` the `sliced_array` values are found.

### edit

The other answer suggests starting with `np.s_`:

```
In [85]: np.s_[:,::3]
Out[85]: (slice(None, None, None), slice(None, None, 3))
```

That produces a tuple of slice objects.  He still has to use `arange` to generate the indices, since the slices themselves don't have `original.shape` information.

`ogrid` can be used to create advanced indexing arrays:

```
In [86]: idx = np.ogrid[:2,:5:3]; idx
Out[86]: 
[array([[0],
        [1]]),
 array([[0, 3]])]
In [88]: original[tuple(idx)]
Out[88]: 
array([[5, 3],
       [8, 6]])
```

`meshgrid` with `sparse=True` gives something similar.  Or with fully populated arrays:

```
In [89]: idx = np.mgrid[:2,:5:3]; idx
Out[89]: 
array([[[0, 0],
        [1, 1]],

       [[0, 3],
        [0, 3]]])

In [90]: original[tuple(idx)]
Out[90]: 
array([[5, 3],
       [8, 6]])
```

There are various ways of transforming that array into a (n,2) set of indices that could be used individually (like `argwhere` in my previous code):

```
In [92]: np.transpose(idx,(1,2,0)).reshape(-1,2)
Out[92]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 3]])

In [93]: for ij in _: print(original[tuple(ij)])
5
3
8
6
```

`ix_` is another handy tool for creating advanced indexing arrays, the equivalent of slices:

```
In [94]: np.ix_(np.arange(2), np.arange(0,5,3))
Out[94]: 
(array([[0],
        [1]]),
 array([[0, 3]]))

In [95]: original[_]
Out[95]: 
array([[5, 3],
       [8, 6]])
```

Keep in mind that indexing with slices, as in `original[:,::3]` produces a `view`.  Indexing with array is slower, since it makes a copy.  And iterative indexing is even slower.

```
In [96]: mask
Out[96]: 
array([[ True, False, False,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False,  True, False]])

In [97]: np.nonzero(mask)      # aka np.where(mask)
Out[97]: (array([0, 0, 1, 1], dtype=int64), array([0, 3, 0, 3], dtype=int64))

In [98]: np.argwhere(mask)
Out[98]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 3],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 3]], dtype=int64)
```

`nonzero` produces a tuple of arrays that can be used directly to index the array:

```
In [99]: original[Out[97]]
Out[99]: array([5, 3, 8, 6])
```

`argwhere` gives the same values, but in a (n,2) form that has to be used iteratively, or in a somewhat awkward:

```
In [100]: original[Out[98][:,0], Out[98][:,1]]
Out[100]: array([5, 3, 8, 6])
```

Comment: A little long but nice answer, thank you sir! Maybe add some tl;dr