# Need to get a row and a column from a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I cannot find a way to get a specific column and row from a text file.

Any help is good, thanks

```
import numpy as np

filename = 'Hear.txt'
data = np.loadtxt(filename, usecols=0, delimiter=',', skiprows=1, dtype=str)
print(data)
```

I can't understand why there isn't a userow=3.

I am after choosing any row and column of my requirement.

Comment: [Possibly useful](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy array slicing to return sliced array and corresponding array indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72645862/numpy-array-slicing-to-return-sliced-array-and-corresponding-array-indices)

Comment: Normally rows are selected from the `data` array, after loading.  e.g. `data[3]` (but it's good to check `data.shape` and `data.dtype` first).  It is possible to skip more rows, and limit the number rows read.